# Display Date separated into day - month - year and combinations of

Tags: javascript, html, date

I'm trying to use the current month, year, month-year and day-month in my html page.

This is the javascript I'm using

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var n = new Date();
var y = n.getFullYear();
var m = n.getMonth();
var d = n.getDate();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d + " " + months[m] + " " + y;
document.getElementById("month-year").innerHTML =  months[m] + " " + y;
document.getElementById("day-month").innerHTML = d + " " + months[m];
document.getElementById("year").innerHTML = y;
document.getElementById("month").innerHTML = months[m];
document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = d;
```

I'm using an html `<a>` tag to call the date, month, year etc, as follows

```
<a id="date"></a>
<a id="month-year"></a>
<a id="day-month"></a>
<a id="year"></a>
<a id="month"></a>
<a id="day"></a>
```

However it only works when I use `<a id="date"></a>` somewhere in the page, if I don't use `<a id="date"></a>` then none of the other tags work.

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3m8cgan9/) to highlight the problem. If you remove `<a id="date"></a>` from the Html section you'll see the problem I'm referring to.

---

Thanks to the answer below

**Full code can be seen at** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3m8cgan9/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your javascript is breaking due to null object on

```
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d + " " + months[m] + " " + y;
```

You should check whether it exists before setting the `innerHTML`. For example:

```
var dateObject = document.getElementById("date");
if (dateObject) dateObject.innerHTML = d + " " + months[m] + " " + y;
```

Comment: Thanks, so what would the entire js look like? I'm sorry I'm not very well versed with js.

Comment: You just use the same pattern for other objects. For example, the next one would be:

`var month_year = document.getElementById("month-year");
if (month_year) month_year.innerHTML =  months[m] + " " + y;`
It's just repeating the same logic, you should be able to replicate it yourself. If you still have a problem, you can just come back with your final code.

Comment: However, when I use the ID twice on the same page, the second instance doesn't work, how can I use the ID multiple times on the same page?

Example, if I use <a id="month-year"></a> twice the second instance doesn't work/show.

Comment: You should never use an ID twice, an ID is unique. You should use class instead.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: All resources are one search away